# How to make divs wrap in columns?

Tags: html, css, printing

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="content">some text</div>
    <div class="content">some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text,</div>
    <div class="content">some text</div>
    <div class="content">some text</div>
    <div class="content">some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer textsome longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
</div>

.page{
  width:450px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.left-column{
  background-color: #E0FFF4;
}


.right-column{
  background-color: #FFE5E6
}
.left-column, .right-column{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.content{
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: #CEBFFF;
}
```

Hi All,

When my content reaches the height of its wrapping container, I want the content to break and for the next div to float over to the next column.

I want this to work nicely for print as well. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can get those divs to wrap in columns using flexbox. It involves using a column flex layout, and setting it to wrap its content.

**Live Demo:**

```css
.page {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.column {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E0FFF4;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: #CEBFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">1. some text</div>
    <div class="content">2. some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text,</div>
    <div class="content">3. some text</div>
    <div class="content">4. some text</div>
    <div class="content">5. some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer textsome longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7cso3m/2/

Comment: Thank you it works :) The only issue now is I always want to have 2 columns and if content is more that 2 columns it breaks into the next page with the same layout. At the moment when I add more content it will create more column.... any clue?

Comment: @NeginBasiri Unfortunately I'm not sure how to make it wrap into another element/page using CSS! You may need to use some JavaScript to accomplish it - you can always ask another question that specifies in very specific terms that you want it to wrap that way.